# Does unopened whole wheat flour have to be refrigerated?

Tags: flour, storage

The organic whole wheat flour that I bought is in a sealed thick plastic bag and has never been opened. Should it be refrigerated (or frozen)? And does opened white flour need to be refrigerated?

My question refers to *unopened* whole wheat flour. And the second part of my question refers to white flour which I now understand is better in the freezer. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Does white whole wheat flour need to be refrigerated?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3105/23376)

Answer (score 1):

Whole wheat flour will turn rancid faster than AP flour because the germ contains oil. For best baking results you should use the flour within one month (opened and unopened) (source: [1](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3126/23376) and [2](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/23376)). You can use the flour even longer but it will taste rancid and the gluten won't work as well as in new flour (source: [3](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/28249/23376)). As far as I know there are no health concerns if older flour is used.

Flour can be refrigerated and be freezed. This will slow down the oxidization. If you want to use the previously chilled flour, make sure that the flour is warm then for good baking results. (source: [1](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3126/23376)).

---

Sources
1: [Does white whole wheat flour need to be refrigerated?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3126/23376)
2: [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/23376)
3. [How to store flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/28249/23376)